# nested select query syntax not consistent

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to recreate a select query to find data from a specific date (find the names of customers who have made an order in april 1997)

The join query i made worked, but when done using a nested select query, the same syntax does not work.

Is this a problem with my syntax? or do nested queries follow different syntax rules.

The code that works:

```
SELECT c.customer_code
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE c JOIN ORDERS o ON c.customer_code = o.customer_code
WHERE order_date BETWEEN 19970331 AND 19970501;
```

The second query that gives me a syntax error (error at where... in the nested query)

```
SELECT c.customer_code
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE c 
WHERE c.customer_code IN (SELECT customer_code
                           FROM order 
                           WHERE order_date BETWEEN 19970331 AND 
                           19970501);
```

I would expect this to work the same, but instead i get Error 1064 at the line "WHERE order_date BETWEEN 19970331 AND 19970501)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining with `order` in second query which is actually `orders` in first query,

```
SELECT c.customer_code
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE c 
WHERE c.customer_code IN (SELECT customer_code
                           FROM ORDERS
                           WHERE order_date BETWEEN 19970331 AND 
                           19970501);
```

Should work.

Comment: @dz12345 *Happy to help. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*